# I can I globally set the cookie domain with PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have the below two lines PHP codes included on every page of my site before session_start():

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );   
session_set_cookie_params( 0, "/", ".domain.com");
```

But when I try to set cookie on my subdomain (m.domain.com) like

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue', time() + 30*24*60*60, "/");
```

The cookie is still set on the domain on m.domain.com

Only if I explicitly set it to

```
 setcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue', time() + 30*24*60*60, "/", 'domain.com');
```

The cookie is set on .domain.com.

But I want want to change all the codes on all the setcookie functions on all the files. Any way can I change it globally? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set a default domain for cookies. `session_set_cookie_params` only affects the session cookie, as you are seeing.

The best you can hope for is to perhaps create your own cookie function with your defaults pre-filled.